# How to transform this into a standard SDP problem?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

How to transform this problem, $$\min_{x_1, x_2} x_1 + x_2$$

$$\text{subject to} \\ \|P_\Omega(X-Z)\|_{F}^2 \leq x_1\\
\lambda\| X \|_{\text{tr}} \leq x_2$$

to the standard SDP problem,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^p} & c^T x \\
\text{subject to} & x_1 A_1 + \cdots + x_p A_p \preceq B,
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Given that solving $\| X \|_{\text{tr}}$ is equivalent to the optimization problem defined as,
$$\max_{Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}} \text{trace}(X^T Y) \\
$$
$$\text{subject to} 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_m & Y \\
Y^T & I_n
\end{array}
\right]\succeq 0$$

I know that $\text{trace}(X^T Y) = \langle X,Y\rangle$, so solving $\| X \|_{\text{tr}}$, so it actually looks very much like the conic problem, but how to transform that into standard SDP, where $c$ and $x$ are vectors?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Maryam Fazel's PhD thesis? [Matrix Rank Minimization with Applications](https://faculty.washington.edu/mfazel/thesis-final.pdf) (pdf)?

Comment: don't you have constraints? I mean the minimum of every norm is $0$...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I didn't have chance to look at it yet. Could you tell me which part might be important for this proof?

Comment: @user251257 Actually I have $\|\left(P_\Omega(X-Z)\right)^TP_\Omega(X-Z)\|_{tr} \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @v-2 you should include it in your question.

Comment: @user251257 My original problem is post here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993751/how-to-convert-the-matrix-completion-problem-to-the-standard-sdp-form?noredirect=1#comment4099232_1993751. In this version I tried to simplify it a little bit to make things easier.