# Strong duality result for non-convex problem with two quadratic functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming

We are given the problem
\begin{equation}\label{primal}
    \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{x}{\text{minimize}} & & x^TA_0x+2b_0^Tx+c_0  \\
    & \text{subject to}            & & x^TA_1x+2b_1^Tx+c_1 \leq 0 \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the $A_i$ are symmetric matrices which are NOT asssumed to be positive semi-definite; this is why this is a non-convex optimisation problem.

I am able to derive its dual problem using Schur complement trick as
\begin{equation}\label{dual}
    \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{\gamma, \lambda}{\text{maximize}} & & \gamma  \\
    & \text{subject to}            & & \lambda \geq 0 \\
    &                              & & \begin{bmatrix}A_0+\lambda A_1 & b_0 + \lambda b_1 \\ (b_0 + \lambda b_1)^T & c_0 + \lambda c_1 - \gamma\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now the reference claims that the dual problem of the SDP is an SDP with variables $X\in S^n, x\in R^n$
\begin{equation}\label{dualdual}
    \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{x, X}{\text{minimize}} & &   {tr}(A_0X)+2b_0^T x + c_0\\
    & \text{subject to}            & & {tr}(A_1X)+2b_1^Tx+c_1 \leq 0\\
    &                              & & \begin{bmatrix}X & x \\ x^T & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
How can I derive this?

Answer (score 2):

Taking hints form this
[Derive the dual of the semidefinite program $\max_Y{\rm Tr}(X^T Y)$ subject to $\begin{pmatrix}I&Y\\ Y^T&I\end{pmatrix}\succeq0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980629/derive-the-dual-of-the-semidefinite-program-max-y-rm-trxt-y-subject-to?rq=1)

I was able to work out the following:
We introduce Lagrange variables $\alpha$ and $\begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & \beta\end{bmatrix}$ and write the Lagrangian as $\mathcal L(\gamma, \lambda, \alpha, X, x, \beta) = -\gamma - \langle \alpha, \lambda \rangle -\langle\begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & \beta\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}A_0+\lambda A_1 & b_0 + \lambda b_1 \\ (b_0 + \lambda b_1)^T & c_0 + \lambda c_1 - \gamma\end{bmatrix}\rangle$. Now the dual function is $g(\alpha, X, x, \beta)=\inf_{\gamma, \lambda}\mathcal L(\gamma, \lambda, \alpha, X, x, \beta) = \begin{cases}-\langle X, A_0\rangle-2\langle x, b_0\rangle-\langle\beta, c_0\rangle & -I + \beta =0, \ \alpha + \langle X, A_1\rangle+2\langle x, b_1\rangle+\langle\beta, c_1\rangle \\ -\infty & otherwise\end{cases}$. Now, substituting $\beta=I$ and using $\alpha\succeq 0$ this can be written as the following dual problem

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{x, X}{\text{minimize}} & &   {tr}(A_0X)+2b_0^T x + c_0\\
    & \text{subject to}            & & {tr}(A_1X)+2b_1^Tx+c_1 \leq 0\\
    &                              & &  \begin{bmatrix}X & x \\ x^T & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The last inequality is the condition that Lagrangian multiplier should be PSD.