# "Shadow prices" interpretation of the dual certificate of nuclear norm optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, nuclear-norm, matrix-completion

In nuclear norm based matrix completion, there exists a low rank matrix $M$ of which only the indicies in $\Omega$ are sampled. [Candes and Recht (2008)](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/MatrixCompletion.pdf) recover the original matrix using following optimization problem.

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize   } &\quad \| X \|_* \tag{P1}\\
\text{subject to  } &\quad X_{ij} = M_{ij}\quad (i,j) \in \Omega.
\end{align}
$$

Then, they prove that $M$ is actually the minimum of P1 by showing that there exists a "dual certificate" $\lambda$ such that

$$ P_\Omega(\lambda) \in \partial \| M \|_* $$

where $P_\Omega$ is the sampling operator that sets all elements not in $\Omega$ to zero, and $\partial \| M\|_*$ denotes the subdifferential of the nuclear norm at $M$.

I am trying to understand the intuition behind this particular dual certificate. For a given, $M$, can I construct that dual certificate and gain some understanding about this solution? For example, there is this idea of "[shadow prices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91504/shadow-price-in-linear-programming)," where the Lagrangian variable (which is just the dual certificate), is somehow the change in the cost if you "relax" the constraint. Can I somehow similarly interpret the dual certificate here?

For example, would it be correct to say that the $(i,j)$th element of $\lambda$ is the amount that the nuclear norm of the solution would change if I increased the value of $M_{ij}$, assuming $(i,j) \in \Omega$?

Comment: Why don't you build some intuition for the problem by trial-and-error coding some optimizers instead of stuffing your head full of fancily branded concepts?

Comment: I'd like very much to do so, @mathreadler. While I can "code some optimizers" to minimize P1 (and have done so), I don't know how to obtain the corresponding "dual certificate,"  which is the object I am interested in understanding.

Comment: Nuclear norm minimization can be written as a [semidefinite program](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704271/339790). Then find its [dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/746883/339790).